# JDBC HashMap persistance

Tags: jdbc, hashmap

I'm trying to persist Instance `HashMap ReQuiredSkills with a lot of elements in a simple table 'Skills' (BOOLEAN).
My goal is to iterate through given map and for every Key == tables.column_name set map's value(true or false). There is piece of code:

```
{statement=connection.prepareStatement("select * from skills limit 1");
        ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData =resultSet.getMetaData();
        statement=connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO skills values(" +
                "default,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        int countColumn = resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount();
        for (int i = 2; i < countColumn; i++ ) {
            String name = resultSetMetaData.getColumnName(i);
            System.out.println(name.toUpperCase());

            if(vacancy.getSkillsRequired().get(name.toUpperCase()) == true){
                statement.setBoolean(i, true);
            } else {
                statement.setBoolean(i, false);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(vacancy.getSkillsRequired());
        statement.executeUpdate();*/
        connection.commit();}
```

There is relation for vacancy : skills as 1 to 1, I've got no problem with persisting vacancy which PRIMARY KEY(id) as a FOREIGN KEY for skills table. So, I try to extract column name through ResulSetMetaData object, set default value for skills_id and iterate through instance hashmaprequredSkills and set values which are obligated for this vacancy.

Comment: JDBC does not specify support for maps in anyway, so how and why do you think it could be useful in prepared statements?

Comment: In any case, you can iterate over the entry set of a map.

Comment: Well, my point is about preparing long statement with loads of "?,?,?..".

Comment: It sounds like you have an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Describe the problem you are trying to solve, not some partial solution you think might work, but can't get to work. In any case, if you are inserting into a table with two columns, you shouldn't have _'loads of "?, ?, ?.."'_, you'd have two parameters. And iterating over the map entry set and using batched execution would likely work.

Comment: Sorry for shorty answer, got internet problems. No, my table is kinda chain of required skills (i'm writing my pet vacancy-searcher) and its structure like: id |skill1 
(varchar )|skill2|...|skill n and their value are Boolean.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with details, don't put it in comments.